# How do I hide "What to Watch" on YouTube using CSS?

Tags: html, css, youtube

I use Stylish to customize how my YouTube homepage (subscriptions) looks. On http://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions, I want to hide the "What to Watch" tab.

This is what I found.

```
<span class="yt-uix-button-content">What to Watch </span>
```

If I just use this:
`.yt-uix-button-content{
    display:none;
  }`
it hides the "Upload" button as well.

Is there a way to include "What to Watch" text in the code or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You must to use CSS path and ":first-child" :

```css
body div#appbar-content div#appbar-nav li:first-child span.yt-uix-button-content{
    display:none;
}
```

[CSS :first-child pseudo-element - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This slightly more specific CSS selector worked for me:

```
#appbar-nav span.yt-uix-button-content { display: none }
```